# Use stacking order when distributing objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have sequences of images that I group-select in Windows Explorer and drag or paste into Illustrator.

The order of these images are important, and I want to distribute them across the artboard while maintaining the stacking order such that the top image is on the left (or right), and the images should distribute sequentially right (or left) according to that stacking order (e.g. the 2<sup>nd</sup> image in stack would be the next image to the right, 3<sup>rd</sup> in stack the next image to the right, etc.).

However, the distribute function doesn't seem to take account of stacking order, and instead, they seem to be place at random with respect to stacking order (as far as I can tell).

Is there a distribution script out there, or something, that would allow me to distribute and keep the order of the stacking?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How many images are there?

Comment: As far as I'm aware one first need to link or embed all the images, *then* you can alter the stacking order, *then* you can distribute. - i.e. images need to be already referenced. When placing multiple images I *believe* AI places images alphabetically based on the file titles - I don't think there is any stacking order for multi-image placement beyond this.